# Flutter - Linear Gradient not taking colors as a array of colors

Tags: android, ios, flutter, colors

I was actually preparing a login screen and decided to use a linear gradient as a background.
I actually upgraded my Flutter SDK from 1.20 to 1.22 in the stable channel.
Please click on the below links to check the problem

[The code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhI7x.png)

[The error shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvWpY.png)

Show what should I do.

Thank you.

Comment: use your code with the error of  "colors" it works fine.

Comment: But when I hit run in VSCode it says there are errors and asks me if I want to debug anyway. I am scared if there is a problem even after debugging with errors. And I have a doubt, will it be okay if the app is build with this error. Like won't it become a runtime error. Anyways thanks the suggestion. I shall definitely try it out

Comment: it will be okay if you build app with this error.

Comment: It is working now. Thanks. I am much obliged

Answer (score 1):

use `flutter clean` and `flutter pub cache repair` in command line ,
then restart the ide

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one probably there could be some version mismatch.

```
Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topRight,
              end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.red])),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Hello Gradient!',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 48.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      )
```

Comment: Ya, maybe a version difference as it was working well in 1.20 version and after upgrading to 1.22 Version the problem started. Anyway thanks for the suggestion. I shall try it out

Comment: i think it edit to `List` in 1.22 version of Flutter

Comment: Actually it is working fine now. I reinstalled flutter SDK. Moreover I forgot to tell that I had enabled web development in flutter. Maybe it was the root root cause. Sorry for not telling it. Thanks for all your valuable suggestions. I am much obliged